# JPassword field insert different data on ms access

Tags: java, database, ms-access-2007

my password is "tip" but i get different data on ms access. it shows like this [C@1fd90d9 here's my code

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

    //initialize variables
            String Fname = txtFname.getText();
            String Lname = txtSname.getText();
            String username = txtEadd.getText();
            char[] cuspassword = txtpass.getPassword();
            //String cuspassword = new String(txtpass.getPassword());
            String town = txtTown.getText();
            int PNum = Integer.parseInt((String)txtP.getText());
            String gender = String.valueOf(cmbGen.getSelectedItem());    
            String question = String.valueOf(comboQ.getSelectedItem());
            String ans = txtAns.getText();   

            DataBaseDriver driver = new DataBaseDriver();  

            Object isource = evt.getSource();
            if (isource == btnO) {

            int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Is this Ok?", "Confirm Dialog", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            switch (answer) {
                case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
            String insertJQuery = "Insert into UserAccount(Fname,Lname,username,cuspassword,town,PNum,gender,question,ans)"
                    + "values "
                    +"('"+Fname+"','"+Lname+"','"+username+"','"+cuspassword+"','"+town+"',"+PNum+",'"+gender+"','"+question+"','"+ans+"')";


            driver.insertQuery1(insertJQuery);             
            break;
                case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
            break;    }
            dispose();        
            new HotelReservation();

        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please try again","Access Denied",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

when i'm trying to convert to string the char[], i dont get any data on password. 
here's my insertquery code

```
public void insertQuery1(String query){
    loadDriver();
    makeConnection();
    try{

        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Register now?","Insert Data", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        switch(option){
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
            stmt=con.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(query);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Log In",
                "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
      closeAll();
      break;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                break;
    }     
        }

    catch (SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Duplicate username",
                "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 }    
}
```

Comment: your commented line is correct

Comment: use `String cuspassword = new String(txtpass.getPassword());` not `char[] cuspassword = txtpass.getPassword();`  `new String(char[])` will convert char array to string.

Comment: when i use that, the password did not save in ms access. i use memo as data type for password in ms access. i dont know whats wrong

Comment: .it's strange if password does't save when use `String cuspassword` .print `insertJQuery` and see is your query is correct ..

Comment: i added to my post my insert query code in my databasedriver class. can u check if there's somthing wrong?

Comment: i checked but i can't test it .you can debug your code or add sout and see does your execute() method get executed or not.do you get any errors ?

Comment: i dont have any error sir. just my password not saving in database. and i dont know why. :(

Comment: when i try to use char[], it shows different data on my db from what i input on my password

Comment: so when you use `String` it shows nothing on db?? that's strange.print query and execute manually on console and see whether   there is same problem or not?

Comment: slr. my code is ok now. I use the char[] then convert it to string. And It works. Also the code in my comment line. thanks sir